# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hg0dbjgz/mysqlclient/

Tags: python, mysql

I can not install the `mysqlclient` in CentOS7.2 using pip:

```
$ pip install "mysqlclient"
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: did not found the command
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-hg0dbjgz/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-hg0dbjgz/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-hg0dbjgz/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hg0dbjgz/mysqlclient/
```

And I have install my MySQL correctly in my server.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.38, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

But I can not install

Answer (score 1):

You should install the `python-devel` and `mysql devel` first use yum:

```
yum install python-devel mysql-community-devel -y
```

then you can install `mysqlclient`